# Content Assist for JSF2 + CDI (weld) beans + Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, cdi, helios

Im trying JSF2 CDI (weld) beans in eclipse helios instead of `ManagedBeans`, but can't do the auto completion inside the expression language for my `Named` beans (the `#{myNamedBean.`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>`}` thingy)

But OTOH with ManagedBeans, the content assist works well .. 
Is the content assist for CDI beans supported yet in Eclipse Helios?

Anybody got experiences in this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Install [JBoss tools](http://jboss.org/tools). Then by adding `<nature>org.jboss.tools.jsf.jsfnature</nature>` to the `natures` section of the `.project` file, the support improved in my Eclipse J2EE Helios edition. (This step is probably equal to `Configure->Add JSF Capabilities` in the project settings.) The context completion then works for `cc.attrs.<ctrl-space>` when building component compositions, but sadly still not for any `@ManagedBean`s.
2. Switch from ManagedBeans to CDI: I changed all `@ManagedBean`s to `@javax.inject.Named` and the scopes to `@javax.enterprise.context.*Scoped` etc. I also enable CDI Support in the project settings. Then I get context completion on beans in `.xhtml`!

First limitation: It only works when the EL is part of an attribute value. It does not work if you just use `#{EL}` somewhere else on the `.xhtml` page.

Second limitation: If you define the name of your bean via a constant, it is not recognized for context competion: Does not work: `@Named(value = MyBean.BEANNAME)`. You have to set the name as a String, like: `@Named(value = "myBean")`

Third limitation: If you use parameterised method calls (e.g. with Tomcat7 or Glassfish), this is not supported by autocomplete. The autocomplete only shows get/set/is properties of the bean.

Note: It works out of the box in Netbeans 7.

Comment: When we add `<nature>org.jboss.tools.jsf.jsfnature</nature>` to the .project file is there any problem to deploy the project on Glassfish or to use Glassfish plugin in Eclipse? And which of all JBoss tools we must to install to get the content assist for facelets, when we don't want to install all JBoss tools?

Comment: First: I don't think that there is going to be any problem mit Glassfish. 
Second: Try all with JSF and CDI in their names.

Comment: With Eclipse Kepler and JBoss Tools 4.1.0.1: `@ManagedBean`s work, autocompletion works for EL expressions everywhere not just in attributes, and parameterized method calls autocomplete as well.

Comment: For CDI Beans (with JBoss Tools installed), right click on the project, then Configure -> Add CDI (Context and Dependency Injection) support...

Answer (score 2):

If there is any support, it would be from [JBoss Tools](http://jboss.org/tools).

Comment: thank you for the info, but i was thinking of something that is not specific for jboss

Comment: @Albert Kam this is a plugin for eclipse I think

Answer (score 0):

Before you install JBossTools, please note that for EL auto complete support and managed bean mapping all you need is these 2 components from the JBoss Tool set.

```
1. JBoss Tools JSF
2. JBoss Tools Visual Page Editor
```

If you do not select these specific tools then all the 20+ tools will get installed.

Also, note that sometimes your default file *.xhtml association will not change after tool installation. You may have to manually change file association preference. `File>Preference>File Associations.` Select *.xhtml and `set "JBoss Tools Visual Page Editor" as the default editor.`