# autocomplete JSF2 expression language

Tags: autocomplete, jsf-2, helios

I'm trying to run my first Hello World application (JSF2 Facelets on jboss 5.0).
I'm using helios SR2, and I have no assist for expression language. Actually I've managed to run the Hello World application successfully, however I think I'd need autocomplete for bigger projects. Did anybody have the same issue and managed to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer at:

[Content Assist for JSF2 + CDI (weld) beans + Eclipse Helios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122189/content-assist-for-jsf2-cdi-weld-beans-eclipse-helios/5881723#5881723)

I got it working in Eclipse Helios with JBoss Tools installed and by using CDI @Named instead of @ManagedBeans.